# MySQL Error Line 1 [INSERT INTO]

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i got this error and this is my query

```
insert into `products` (original_id,name,image_url,buy_url,short_description,long_description,sale_price,retail_price,brand,keyword,category_name,store_name,provider_name) values (5068122-EC1155705-5.5M,Eastland Plainview Shoes (Black) - Women's Shoes - 5.5 M,http://www.shoes.com/productimages/shoes_iaec1155705.jpg,http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_click?lid=41000000025255752&pid=5068122-EC1155705-5.5M&adurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shoes.com%2FShopping%2Fproductdetails.aspx%3Fcatalog%255Fname%3Dweb%26pg%3D5068122%26p%3DEC1155705&usg=AFHzDLv0Y4C7BN1pbi4RzmWWTgLx7J7uBw&pubid=21000000000526055,Eastland keeps it timeless and classy with these smart and sturdy Plainview oxfords. Soft full grain leather upper in a casual oxford style with a round plain toe. Contouring double stitching and an Eastland side logo tag add classic detail. Five eyelet g,Eastland keeps it timeless and classy with these smart and sturdy Plainview oxfords. Soft full grain leather upper in a casual oxford style with a round plain toe. Contouring double stitching and an Eastland side logo tag add classic detail. Five eyelet grommeted lacing and a smooth leather padded collar and tongue create a comfortable customizable fit. Textile lining and cushioning footbed flexible stitched midsole. Durable polyurethane traction outsole with a sturdy 1 1/4 inch heel.,77.00,77.00,Eastland,Eastland Plainview Shoes (Black) - Women's Shoes - 5.5 M Womens|Casual Eastland US adult Black female  Apparel & Accessories > Shoes   5.5 M,Apparel & Accessories > Shoes,Eastland,gan)
```

> On line: 127 File C:\web\filesearch\index.php You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'M,Eastland Plainview Shoes (Black) - Women's Shoes - 5.5 M,http://www.shoes.com/' at line 1

whats wrong with that?

line  line: 127 is  this

```
  mysql_query($query) or die($query . "<br />On line: " . __LINE__ . " File " . __FILE__ . " " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: I highly suggest you read up on protecting yourself from SQL injection, and to use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your string values within Quotes for your query. You have big strings but they have no quotation marks around them, thats the error. For example `5068122-EC1155705-5.5M` should be `"5068122-EC1155705-5.5M"` or `'5068122-EC1155705-5.5M'`

Comment: Yes, or avoid the whole issue by using query parameters.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the response but it doesn't solve my problem.. still same error exists

Comment: because you have to do it for every string value, not just one

Answer (score 1):

Also Use mysql_escape_string for values that are being inserted after enclosing them in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ler me see the codes. I will come up with something shorly

Comment: @Roger This statement is not correct, you can do so for FLOAT and other numeric values aswell

Answer (score 0):

Please update the post with your new query. If you have properly updated the query with QUOTES,  The next problem may be the data type mismatch or the length mismatch between your string and the columns defined.